# Invalid JSON literal: xxx when calling ASMX service from Angular8

Tags: json, angular, web-services, asmx, angular8

I have a problem with calling ASMX webservice using Angular 8. I have seen resolutions for same error when calling from Ajax, maybe similar workaround will help, but I don't know how to do that in NG.

**Problem:**

When I call the ASMX webservice with string parameter, I get the "Invalid JSON literal: xxx" error. From Ajax, the solution is to JSON.stringify() the data which are actually the parameters of the webservice call. But I don't know how to do that in Angular.

I have tried to stringify the HttpParams object, but it doesn't work, because then it do not comply with options definition. Also when I try to remove 'Content-Type': 'application/json', I run into another error and I can't run the webservice from Angular.

Here is code of webservice call in angular:

```
    const options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({
                      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
                      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'
                    }),
                    params: new HttpParams().set('Page', page.toString())
                                            .set('Count', count.toString())
                                            .set('Filter', (filter === undefined ? '' : filter))
                                            .set('FilterClub', (filterClub === undefined ? '' : filterClub))
     };

    return this.http.get<PlayerResponse>(this.listUrl, options)
          .pipe();
```

Maybe also the webservice definition will be of some use for you (only start of C# code):

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public PlayerData List(int Page = 1, int Count = 20, string Filter = "", string FilterClub = "")
        {
```

I expect the webservice to be able to run also with string parameters. Interesting thing is, that if I use only integer parameters, webservice is called properly and returns correct data. In other words, from the example above, when I do NOT filter for fields Filter and FilterClub, (&Filter=&FilterClub=), the webservice returns data as expected.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Any help is much appretiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried almost everything. Unfortunately the only thing I did not try is to add quotes around the value of parameter. I didn't expect it will work but it does. So here is solution how to send string literals when using application/json Content-Type to call ASMX webservice:

```
    const options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({
                      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
                      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'
                    }),
                    params: new HttpParams().set('Page', page.toString())
                                            .set('Count', count.toString())
                                            .set('Filter', (filter === undefined ? '' : '\'' + filter + '\''))
                                            .set('FilterClub', (filterClub === undefined ? '' : '\'' + filterClub + '\''))
     };
```